# How do I add a new line into my array with new data grabbed from Active Directory?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am new to Powershell, and I am trying to create a .csv file output from this script that I can quickly use to upload into a database.

It all works well and outputs exactly how I want it to, but I can only do one user at a time.

I have a loop set up that runs back through the script, but I'm missing the part where I need the array to output on a new line.

Any suggestions?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

[string]$script:iviisID = Read-Host "Enter iViis ID number"

$AddUser = {

    $script:name = Read-Host "Enter username (first.last)"
    
    $script:number = Read-Host "Enter users Phone Number"

    $script:gender = Read-Host "Enter 1 for Male, 2 for Female"

    if ($gender -eq 1)
    {
        $script:gender = "Male"
    } else
    {
        $script:gender = "Female"
    }

    $script:role = Read-Host "Enter 1 for Foreman, 2 for Contract Manager"

    if ($role -eq 1)
    {
        $script:role = "Foreman@er"
    } else
    {
        $script:role = "ContractManager@er"
    }

    $user = Get-ADUser -identity $name -Properties *

    $firstName = $user | foreach {$_.givenName}
    $lastName = $user | foreach {$_.sn}
    $employeeID = $user | foreach {$_.employeeID}
    $email = $user | foreach {$_.mail}

    $array =@(
        [PSCustomObject] @{
        FirstName = $firstName
        Surname = $lastName
        FirstNames = $firstName
        LastName = $lastName
        EMPLOYEEID = $script:iviisID
        PGID = $employeeID
        EmployeeCode = $script:iviisID
        UserID = [string]$script:iviisID + "@er"
        ENABLEDFLAG = "1"
        EmailAddress = $email
        PersonalPhoneNumber = $number
        Role = $role
        Password = "plant.box.dog"
        Gender = $gender
        PreferredName = $firstName
        Category = "Employee"
        }
    )

    $newUser = Read-Host "Would you like to add another user? (y/n)"

    if($newUser -eq "y")
    {
        [int]($script:iviisID) = $iviisID
        $script:iviisID++



        &$AddUser
    }
    else
    {
        $array | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Test\Employees.csv
    }
}

&$AddUser
```

This is the example of my code, if I run through this it ends up giving me a .csv with only the latest run through of the loop that I have run, but I have no way to retain the information I have already added.

Apologies if the way I have created this is a bit odd, as I am just learning Powershell and experimenting, but if anybody could direct me in the right direction or suggest anything then please let me know :)

Edit: Added missing code

Comment: Please add the missing code (the loop). Fixing the issue is likely by adding `-Append` to your `Export-Csv` statement but it probably can be simplified if you add the missing code

Comment: Thanks Santiago, I have added it now. Sorry I missed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code, the reason why your Csv only gets the last user created is because **each recursive call to the `$AddUser` scriptblock is overwriting the previous Csv file**, your code could be solved by adding `-Append`:

```
$array | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Test\Employees.csv -Append
```

However, instead of using a recursive call I recommend you to use a `while` loop, much easier this way and there is no need to use `$script:` scoped variables. In this case the `while` loop is wrapped in an outer invoked scriptblock to enable directly piping the output from the loop to `Export-Csv`.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

& {
    [int] $iviisID = Read-Host 'Enter iViis ID number'

    while ($true) {
        $name = Read-Host 'Enter username (first.last)'
        $number = Read-Host 'Enter users Phone Number'
        $gender = Read-Host 'Enter 1 for Male, 2 for Female'
        if ($gender -eq 1) {
            $gender = 'Male'
        }
        else {
            $gender = 'Female'
        }

        $role = Read-Host 'Enter 1 for Foreman, 2 for Contract Manager'
        if ($role -eq 1) {
            $role = 'Foreman@er'
        }
        else {
            $role = 'ContractManager@er'
        }

        $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $name -Properties givenName, sn, employeeId, mail

        [PSCustomObject] @{
            FirstName           = $user.givenName
            Surname             = $user.sn
            FirstNames          = $firstName
            LastName            = $lastName
            EMPLOYEEID          = $iviisID
            PGID                = $user.employeeID
            EmployeeCode        = $iviisID
            UserID              = [string] $iviisID + '@er'
            ENABLEDFLAG         = '1'
            EmailAddress        = $user.mail
            PersonalPhoneNumber = $number
            Role                = $role
            Password            = 'plant.box.dog'
            Gender              = $gender
            PreferredName       = $firstName
            Category            = 'Employee'
        }

        $newUser = Read-Host 'Would you like to add another user? (y/n)'

        if ($newUser -eq 'y') {
            $iviisID++
            continue
        }

        # if `$newUser` not equal to 'Y' breaks the while loop here
        break
    }
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Test\Employees.csv
```

Comment: Wow, that was so simple and your code is much more elegant than mine! Thank you very much for the help, I appreciate the time and effort!

Comment: @csteel217 glad it was helpful, happy to help :)